# Problem exporting higher resolution images in v11.1

Tags: export

The following code (Mac, V11.1)

> g = SphericalPlot3D[1, {theta, 0, Pi}, {phi, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotPoints -> 10];
>
> Export["sphere1.png", g, ImageResolution -> 30, ImageSize -> 1000];
>
> Export["sphere2.png", g, ImageResolution -> 300, ImageSize -> 1000];

produces a fine sphere1.png and **just a gray image** for sphere2.png.

Note that if I don't indicate the image size

> Export["sphere2.png", g, ImageResolution -> 300];

the result is a find image thats 1500x1667 so there seems to be nothing too-big about the desired image width of 1000

Comment: Try `Export[..., Show[g, ImageSize -> ...], ImageResolution -> ...]`. Sorry, I haven't tries, but this would be my first try.

Comment: A resolution of 72 is standard, `2*72` will give an image twice larger, in pixels.